# How do I create an encoding session with VideoCore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, videocore

I'm integrating the [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) RTMP encoder into my app, but I'm having trouble starting a new encoding session.  I see the `VCSimpleSession` class, but how do I start the encoder and see the output?

```
VCSimpleSession *mySession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] init];
```

I don't see the preview view.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoCore uses simple and complex graphs.  `VCSimpleSession` is the easiest way to setup the encoder.

There are a few different initializers for `VCSimpleSession`:

```
- (instancetype) initWithVideoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
                         frameRate:(int)fps
                           bitrate:(int)bps;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (instancetype) initWithVideoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
                         frameRate:(int)fps
                           bitrate:(int)bps
           useInterfaceOrientation:(BOOL)useInterfaceOrientation;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (instancetype) initWithVideoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
                         frameRate:(int)fps
                           bitrate:(int)bps
           useInterfaceOrientation:(BOOL)useInterfaceOrientation
                       cameraState:(VCCameraState) cameraState;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (instancetype) initWithVideoSize:(CGSize)videoSize
                         frameRate:(int)fps
                           bitrate:(int)bps
           useInterfaceOrientation:(BOOL)useInterfaceOrientation
                       cameraState:(VCCameraState) cameraState
                        aspectMode:(VCAspectMode) aspectMode;
```

`videoSize` is the desired resolution of your encoded video.

`fps` is the video frame rate.  Depending on your server settings, you will probably want to make this 30, maybe even 60 if your server supports it.

`bps` is the video bitrate, in bits per second.

`useInterfaceOrientation` is used to notify the encoder of device orientation changes..  Passing in `YES` will tell the encoder to rotate the video when you rotate the device.

`cameraState` is used to start the encoder with your desired camera source.  The `VCCameraState` enum has two values: `VCCameraStateFront` and `VCCameraStateBack`.

`aspectMode` is used to set the aspect mode of your preview view.  VCAspectMode has two values: `VCAspectModeFit` (your sessions video preview should "aspect fit" into its parent view, and `VCAscpectModeFill` (scale your video preview to fill its parent view).

Use one of these initializers to create a new session.  Make sure you retain the session after initialization as a property or ivar.  After initialization, add the sessions's `previewView` property as a subview to some `UIView` on your view controller.

To connect to a server, use the `startRtmpSessionWithURL:` method on your session.  To stop your encoder, call `endRtmpSession`.

Your full setup will probably look something like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewView; // This is a UIView on your view controller
@property (weak, nonatomic) VCSimpleSession* session;

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.session = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720) frameRate:30 bitrate:1000000 useInterfaceOrientation:NO];

    [self.previewView addSubview:_session.previewView];
    [self.previewView bringSubviewToFront:self.session.previewView]
    [_session startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://192.168.1.151/live" andStreamKey:@"myStream"];
}
```

When you're done:

```
[self.session endRtmpSession];
```

I've done some work on the VideoCore sample app, you should check it out the [sample view controller](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/blob/master/sample/SampleBroadcaster/SampleBroadcaster/ViewController.mm).